# R CMD Check: Skip 'checking re-building of vignette outputs'

Tags: r, travis-ci, r-package

I build my R package using `--no-build-vignettes` because the vignette takes very long to run. Hence, I also want to avoid that "R CMD Check " checks for the vignette re-build.
I tried to use `--no-check-vignettes`. However this gets ignored (not sure if it exists at all).

Another reason to ignore my vignette is the fact that I get in trouble on Travis CI because this step exceeds 10 mins (which causes the build to abort).

Is there a way to avoid the building and checking of vignettes of an R package? (Besides setting all vignette chunks to `eval = FALSE`)

Answer (score 18):

One needs to set `r_check_args: "--no-build-vignettes --ignore-vignettes"` in `.travis.yml` to skip rebuilding of vignettes.

In RStudio `--no-build-vignettes` needs to go into the "build options" and and `--ignore-vignettes` into the "check options" in the configuration GUI in the "Build" pane.

Comment: I found these pages helpful: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/ https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486518-Customizing-Package-Build-Options

Comment: In 2019, I get `Error: '--no-vignettes' is defunct: use '--no-build-vignettes' instead`. But using the `--no-build-vignettes` still runs `checking re-building of vignette outputs ...` but produces no vignette output and causes warnings:  `❯ checking files in ‘vignettes’ ... WARNING: Files in the 'vignettes' directory but no files in 'inst/doc':...` and `❯ checking package vignettes in ‘inst/doc’ ... WARNING: Package vignette without corresponding PDF/HTML: ...`